# how to take input an array[] of StringBuffer in java

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

I wanted to take a input an array of `StringBuffer` for user in java but it doesn't work properly:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B obj =new B();
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int l;
        System.out.println("enter the length of string ");
        l=sc.nextInt();

        StringBuffer sb[]=new StringBuffer[l];


         for(int i=0;i<sb.length;i++) 
         {
             System.out.println("enter a string "+(i+1) +" : ");
             sb[i]=sb[i].append(sc.nextLine()); // in this line they will give error
         }


        obj.inputstring( sb);


    }
```

Comment: This `sb[i]=sb[i].append(sc.nextLine());` will give you a `NullPointerException` because `sb[i]` is `null` before you assign it, use `sb[i]=new StrinBuffer(sc.nextLine());` instead

Comment: Also, as the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) says, you should be using `StringBuilder` instead

Comment: i want to take inupt an arry of StringBuffer from user in java.

Comment: @SyedMossawarHussainShah On another note, if you use sc.nextInt() - you will find that the first StringBuffer you create will be instantly taken - you need to call sc.nextLine(); to disregard the "rest" of the line after nextInt().

Comment: Why are you not using a `StringBuilder()` which supports `append()`?

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen You also need to read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#append-java.lang.String-) for `StringBuffer`, although I'd use `StringBuilder` for different reasons

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize  StringBuffer object for each and every sb[i] location.

```
sb[i]=new StringBuffer(sc.nextLine());
```

Refer javadoc for [Array initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html)

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //B obj =new B();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int l;
    System.out.println("enter the length of string ");
    l = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

    StringBuffer sb[] = new StringBuffer[l];

    System.out.println("sb length==" + sb.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("enter a string " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        sb[i] = new StringBuffer(sc.nextLine()); // use StringBuffer(value)
    }
    for(int j=0;j<sb.length;j++){

        System.out.println("string "+j+"="+sb[j]);
    }
    //for(int j=0;j<=sb.length;j++){}
    //System.out.println("sb=="+sb.toString());

}
```

Comment: Do you really need l+1 scanners? One should be more than enough to read everything.

Comment: I have tried with single scanner. it makes some confusion inside the loop. i am checking it.

Comment: Check my comment on question.